# Simple text console in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin, console, eclipse-rcp

I want to build a text console by means of which I can edit a model that's being displayed in a GEF Editor. I guess I can extend the normal Eclipse Console for this. But how can I listen to it?

I want it to work just like a terminal, so I can type in a custom command (such as `+node text=hello` (for "add a node") and then parse (?) it (check whether it's `-node` or `+node`, and get the `text` value) and feed the contents to a command (`new CreateNodeCommand(text)` or similar).

Thanks for any tips on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [here](http://book.javanb.com/eclipse-rich-client-platform-designing-coding-and-packaging-java-applications-oct-2005/ch16lev1sec1.html) in Section 16.1.2. Adding the Debug Perspective and Console View is described how to add a new console. They create a new Message Console, but in the org.eclipse.ui.console you can find the best for you.

There is also another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533000/eclipse-rcp-custom-console).